# How to get bean values in jsp scriplets and store in a input:text value attribute

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

```
<bean:write name="<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>" property="<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>
```

this creates value (`111`)

is it a good practice to do the following:

```
    <input type="text" value=<bean:write name="<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>" property="<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>"/>
```

such that the html generated will look like:

```
<input type="text" value="111"/>
```

Comment: Have you at least tried it before posting this question? If you don't, then do it and come back with a real problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is it a good practice to do it that way then?

Comment: Ok, now your question has really changed. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197 for more info. By the way, in short, **no**, it is not a good practice.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice, and if you'll recall this whole going back-and-forth between "two" users isn't acceptable.

Comment: Of course it's not a good idea to use scriptlets. You should be doing more work on the Java side, and be using JSTL and JSP EL.